# Import Vanilla JavaScript library in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting following error when try to import existing Vanilla JavaScript library to Angular 6 component.
Please suggest how to fix it.

Syntax to import the library, I have written

```
import * as ExistingLibrary from 'app/main/libs/ExistingLibrary.js';
```

> ```
> ExistingLibrary.doJob is not a function
> ```

**External JavaScript library - ExistingLibrary.js**

```
var ExistingLibrary = new (function () {
    this.doJob = doJob;
    function doJob(template, options) {

    function f1(template, options) {}
    function f2(template, options) {}
});
```

Comment: Are you exporting that `ExistingLibrary` object?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, can I export it by adding some piece of code at the beginning or end of the existing library file.

Comment: You probably need `export { ExistingLibrary }` at the end of that existing library file.

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Comment: What is your build setup / bundling / scripts like?

Answer (score 2):

The existing library should probably be a module of some short, so that you module bundler can add it to your module system.

The first thing to look up is if the existing library has a npm package?
In that case you probably should use the NPM version of the existing library, or consider upgrading the existing library to a version that comes with module system.

You probably need something like

```
export const ExistingLibrary = ...
```

or

```
module.exports = ExistingLibrary =
```

If modifying the existing library is not possible, you'll have to configure your module bundler or JS build pipeline to handle libraries that do not include modules and/or require global this. E.g. using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-raw-bundler

Answer (score 2):

```
var ExistingLibrary = new (function () {
    this.doJob = doJob;
    function doJob(template, options) {

    function f1(template, options) {}
    function f2(template, options) {}
});
```

instead of this you need to export the functions like this:

```
export function doJob(template, options) { }
```

Comment: I cannot modify the ExistingLibrary.js, that's an external library.

Comment: At least you don't have to take responsibility for writing one of the ugliest IIFEs in history.

Comment: I completely agree with you I cannot import something which is not exported but I cannot modify the existing library except little adjustments.. such as adding export tag at the staring or end of the existing file.. or some other little adjustments.